# 360 video shot with GoPro has low quality in Unity VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, 360-video

I have to use 360 videos for my next project in Unity. I have a GoPro2 camera which record on 4k/30fps, however the Oculus 2 Quest that I have displays the video in a [bad quality that's not realistic at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO3Jn.jpg). How can I fix it? Here are the settings of my render texture and the video player itself.

[Render Texture]
[image]

[360 Material]
[image]

[Video Player]
[image]

I tried to find a solution but every topic is more than 3 years old and the solutions from back then seem to not work now. Also, I noticed that when I set the aspect ratio from stretch to no scaling, the quality is way better, but its not 360 anymore and half of the screen is black.
[Black Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg2tZ.png)

Comment: please add enough debugging details to help us identify an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use costume compute shader with converting frame pixels to 360 projection algorithm. That isn't the easiest way to solve the problem, but it'll definitely help. Check unity Compute Shaders documentation for more information.